# Apache2 needs 2 restarts to serve nexcloud page again

Tags: server, apache2, nextcloud

If I run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

it seems to run ok. At least it says ok. But the nextcloud login page is not served. The browser gives an error page you get if the site does not exist.

Sometimes, actually only twice until now, it works already the first time. But usually not. Then I have to execute the command again. And after that it always works again.
I looked for error entries in logs but could not find any.

If I check the status of apache2 it says it is ok.
`service apache2 status` gives me:

```
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: Input/output error
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-11-05 13:22:36 CET; 2min 46s ago
  Process: 31106 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31111 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service

Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[31111]: Failed to attach 31111 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud apachectl[31111]: httpd (pid 8519) already running
Nov 05 13:22:36 nextcloud systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

syslog entry if the command works look like this:

```
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Failed to attach 26239 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[26239]: Failed to attach 26239 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: message repeated 3 times: [ apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error]
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Failed to attach 26244 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[26244]: Failed to attach 26244 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:42 nextcloud systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

And if the site is not served it looks like this:

```
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Failed to attach 26417 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[26417]: Failed to attach 26417 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: message repeated 3 times: [ apache2.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/apache2.service, ignoring: Input/output error]
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Failed to attach 26422 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[26422]: Failed to attach 26422 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/apache2.service: No such file or directory
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud apachectl[26422]: httpd (pid 26248) already running
Nov  5 10:39:49 nextcloud systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The error.log at /var/log/apache2 is empty.

Is there anywhere else I can look why this is not working? Any other logfiles. Or did I miss an error in the files I posted?

The system is a LXC container Ubuntu 18.04 running on Proxmox 5.4. All systems are up-to-date. It is only configured to host nextcloud (version 17) with PostgreSQL Database.
Just running the command a second time and everything is fine (every time). I would like to understand the problem where it is coming from. And have information on more places to look for error messages.